# What's a correct way of retrieving data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've posted a few questions seeking clarity in small details about the do's and don't's of javascript, ajax and html. And here's one more. I'm creating a list with javascript by the usage of an api. When making the list I get the correct values for the text. When pressing the button in the row I'm getting the alert message. But the new entry is blank.

Can I add data this way (a for loop getting info and building a string with it baked in)?

OR is it the way I retrieve and store data that is wrong?

EDIT: My data is undefined. Don't I get a string from: data.items[i].Info.drivers?

Part of javascript that talks to an api and gives drivers and cars. This segment is part of a for loop.

```
...+'<h5><data-title="'
       +data.items[i].Info.drivers+'">'
       +data.items[i].Info.drivers
    +'</data></h5>'
    +'<p class="subtitle"><data-title="'
        +data.items[i].Info.cars+'">' 
        +data.items[i].Info.cars
    +'</data></p>'
    + '<input class="adding"type="button" name="vehicle" value="Add book">'...
```

My add code (javascript in html):

```
$(document).on('click', '.adding',function() {
window.alert("active");
    var $this = $(this);
    var drivers = $(this).data('drivers');
    var cars = $(this).data('cars');

alert($(this).data('drivers')); //<----gives alert, says Undefined

$.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php',
    type: 'POST',
data: {
    'driver': drivers,
    'car': cars
},

    success: function(msg) {
                    window.alert("success triggered");
             }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by entry is empty. Is it on api or on front end

Comment: And I think you should add dataType: 'json'

Comment: The list I'm creating is empty. Api works as intended and has the cars and drivers written out properly.

Comment: Is AJAX call successful? Can you open the network tab and see if the AJAX call ends with a 200 status

Comment: Then you should create a html variable containing added list and append it in html

Comment: I don't get anything when looking at network tab. It's blank when I press the button.

Comment: When I add window.alert($(this).data('title').val()); I don't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is referring to the button. By putting the data attributes in the button in the same way the problem is solved.